# turn on p2p and perform discovery from the action bar

Tags: android, p2p

how to do this on the phone??
I have Tried Google sample app and in that how to
turn on Peer to peer and perform discovery from the action bar

Answer (score 6):

Android P2P is now called WiFi Direct.

On the Settings panel select Wi-Fi. You'll see a list of WiFi networks but you want to click the menu button on the lower right (the vertical ...). This opens up a submenu with Wi-Fi Direct as one of the options, select it.

Do this same thing on your other phone. At the bottom of the panel is a 'search for devices' button, hit this on both phones and each should be able to discover the other one. One one of the phones press the name of the other device and then 'send invitation to connect'. The invitation should appear on the other device, accept it. If all goes well they will now be connected.

I did this procedure and was able to get the sample app to work, transferred a photo from my gallery on one phone to the other one.

Comment: can you post some screen short please